# Arduino global variable not in scope of loop function

Tags: pointers, scope, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm working on some code for the esp8266 module and ran into some problems.

Here is how I declare a pointer to the clients array. I do this before the setup which would mean that these variables are also recognized in the loop scope am I right?

```
WiFiClient clients[10];
*WiFiClient p;
p = &clients[0];
```

In this part of the code which is in the loop() function I use the pointer to get check each element of the clients array.

```
for(int i=0; i< sizeof(clients); i++){
  if(*(p+i) == client){
    contain = true;
    break;      
  }  
}
```

The goal of this code is to have an array with all the WiFiClients that are currently connected and to see if, when there is een client.available(), that client already is in the array. 
Later we go through the array again to read all the messages for each client.
But compilation gives this error:
error: 'p' was not declared in this scope

```
   if(*(p+i) == client){
```

which I find confusing as it should be in the scope. Maybe something is wrong with my declaration?

Originally I had it like this:

```
WiFiClient clients[10];
WiFiClient *p;
p = &clients[0];
```

but that gave another error:
error: 'p' does not name a type

p = &clients[0];

but if I then gave p a type it would say that p already was declared with a type.

Comment: You'll need to post some complete code.  This doesn't make sense with what you say.  This line:  p = &clients[0];  can't be at global scope or it would be an error.   SO if you're not getting a compilation error about p not naming a type then that line IS inside some function and is outside the scope of loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understanding what you are doing with the array, but to solve your problem you just need the `p = &clients[0];` line to be right before your for loop:

```
WiFiClient clients[10];
*WiFiClient p;

void loop() {

  // other stuff

  p = &clients[0];
  for(int i=0; i< sizeof(clients); i++){
    if(*(p+i) == client){
      contain = true;
      break;      
    }  
  }
}
```

`p` is already declared at global scope but the address of the `clients` array is not known until runtime.